# Passing DateTime into TryUpdateModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

One property of my model is DateTime. I'm working with DateTime format "d.M.yyyy H:mm", i.e. day.month.year. When I pass date like 11.4.2011 (April 11th, 2011) into TryUpdateModel, it comes back as 4.11.2011, i.e. day and month swaps. Is there any way how can I instruct TryUpdateModel to parse datetime value the way I want, not the way system wants?

Thanks,

Antonin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I discovered that if I use HTTPPost instead of HTTPGet MVC behaves as expected. I don't know why it solves the problem and I am still looking for the full answer to this question.